# Button size with numbers

Tags: css

I have a problem with the width of my looped buttons.
In this screenshot : http://prntscr.com/auzfa5 , you can see that the first 9 buttons ( 1-9 ) have a smaller width than the other buttons.

Basically, I want all the buttons to have the same width no matter what number was put in. But I don't exactly know how?

I use Bootstrap to style my buttons.
Here is the CSS code I used:

```
button {
    border-radius: 15%;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF8DC;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

Short story: I want all the buttons to have the same width.

If you need anything else then please ask it in the comment section and I will respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See currently your width of button is according to its text from 1-9 the text is of single letter but after 9 text is to 2 letters so it will be like this if you use padding.

Apply width to your button and use `text-align:center` to center it align and remove `left` `right` padding.

```
button {
    border-radius: 15%;
    padding: 16px 0;
    width: 60px; // according to u
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF8DC;
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply same `width` to buttons.

```css
button {
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF8DC;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<br/>
<button>100</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was also very helpful ;)